# How to parse out nested JSON with Python

Tags: python, json

Here's the code I have to get the JSON

```
lite = requests.get("https://app.v.com/api/v2/4dfasdfasdfadsfasdfasdfasdf/keywords/list?site_id=000821&format=json")
```

This is what it  looks like

```
{'Response': 
{'responsecode': '200', 'resultsreturned': '100', 'totalresults': '1021', 'nextpage': '/keywords/list?site_id=000000&start=100&format=json', 


'Result': [

{'Id': '18540409', 'Keyword':  blindness', 'KeywordMarket': 'US-en', 'KeywordLocation': None, 'KeywordDevice': 'desktop', 'KeywordTranslation': None, 'KeywordTags': 'banner blindness - 10/18', 'KeywordStats': {'AdvertiserCompetition': '0.0', 'GlobalSearchVolume': '260', 'RegionalSearchVolume': '90', 'LocalSearchTrendsByMonth': {'Nov': '90', 'Oct': '90', 'Sep': '90', 'Aug': '110', 'Jul': '110', 'Jun': '70', 'May': '90', 'Apr': '90', 'Mar': '110', 'Feb': '110', 'Jan': '110', 'Dec': '50'}, 'CPC': '0.0'}, 'KeywordRanking': {'date': '2020-01-05', 'Google': {'Rank': '14', 'BaseRank': '11', 'Url': 'x.com/blog/blindness/'}, 'Bing': {'Rank': '16', 'Url': 'www.x.com/blog/blindness/'}}, 'CreatedAt': '2019-05-01', 'RequestUrl': '/rankings/list?keyword_id=17492833&format=json&from_date=2019-05-01&to_date='}, 

{'Id': '18540410', 'Keyword': 'research', 'KeywordMarket': 'US-en', 'KeywordLocation': None, 'KeywordDevice': 'desktop', 'KeywordTranslation': None, 'KeywordTags': 'keyword research - 11/19', 'KeywordStats': {'AdvertiserCompetition': '0.00564972', 'GlobalSearchVolume': '320', 'RegionalSearchVolume': '170', 'LocalSearchTrendsByMonth': {'Nov': '170', 'Oct': '170', 'Sep': '210', 'Aug': '260', 'Jul': '140', 'Jun': '140', 'May': '170', 'Apr': '170', 'Mar': '210', 'Feb': '210', 'Jan': '110', 'Dec': '110'}, 'CPC': '0.0'}, 'KeywordRanking': {'date': '2020-01-05', 'Google': {'Rank': '75', 'BaseRank': '73', 'Url': 'x.com/blog/research/'}, 'Bing': {'Rank': '120', 'Url': None}}, 'CreatedAt': '2019-11-01', 'RequestUrl': '/rankings/list?keyword_id=18540410&format=json&from_date=2019-11-01&to_date='}]}}
```

Then I create a dictionary

```
litedict = lite.json()
```

and after this I'm only able to see 'Response'

```
print(litedict["Response"])
```

If I try to pull 'result', which is the data I want, I get this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-69-59a1c50ef855> in <module>
----> 1 print(lite2["Result"])

KeyError: 'Result'
```

Any help would be appreciative, I'm very unfamiliar with JSON and I
've searched for the answer for about an hour now.

Comment: Look at the JSON more closely: `Result` is a key in the value of `'Response'`, not the top-level object. `litedict['Response']['Result']` is the expression you want.

Comment: _I’m very unfamiliar with JSON_ In that case what you probably need is a guide/tutorial, and the documentation.

Comment: Do you have a recommendation for one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access the childrens you need to escalate.

**Example**
`litedict["Response"]["Result"][0]`

and you will get

`{'Id': '18540409', 'Keyword':  blindness', 'KeywordMarket': 'US-en', 'KeywordLocation': None, 'KeywordDevice': 'desktop', 'KeywordTranslation': None, 'KeywordTags': 'banner blindness - 10/18', 'KeywordStats': {'AdvertiserCompetition': '0.0', 'GlobalSearchVolume': '260', 'RegionalSearchVolume': '90', 'LocalSearchTrendsByMonth': {'Nov': '90', 'Oct': '90', 'Sep': '90', 'Aug': '110', 'Jul': '110', 'Jun': '70', 'May': '90', 'Apr': '90', 'Mar': '110', 'Feb': '110', 'Jan': '110', 'Dec': '50'}, 'CPC': '0.0'}, 'KeywordRanking': {'date': '2020-01-05', 'Google': {'Rank': '14', 'BaseRank': '11', 'Url': 'x.com/blog/blindness/'}, 'Bing': {'Rank': '16', 'Url': 'www.x.com/blog/blindness/'}}, 'CreatedAt': '2019-05-01', 'RequestUrl': '/rankings/list?keyword_id=17492833&format=json&from_date=2019-05-01&to_date='}`

Answer (score 3):

The problem is clearer if you format the response more uniformly:

```
{
  'Response': {
    'responsecode': '200',
    'resultsreturned': '100',
    'totalresults': '1021',
    'nextpage': '/keywords/list?site_id=000000&start=100&format=json', 
    'Result': [
      {...},
      {...},
    ]
  }
}
```

`Result` is not a key of the top level object, but of the `Response` value. Use `lite['Response']['Result']`.

Comment: It worked great, thanks. Do you have any recommendations for a good tutorial?